# d3 v5 force simulation: how to use stop & tick

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to understand stopping d3.force simulations. According to [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation), I should be able to do `simulation.stop()` and then either `restart` or `tick` through it. However the code below simply stops working if I uncomment the `simulation.stop()` line. It seems that the `simulation.tick()` lines are ignored altogether. What am I doing wrong?

I need this to debug the node position evolution. I would like to see the nodes positioned at (50, 50) and (51, 51) and then move away from there with every tick.

```html
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var nodes = [{"x": 50, "y": 50}, {"x": 51, "y": 51}];
    var height = 200,
        width = 200;

    var svg = d3
        .select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g").attr("class", "node");

    node.append("circle").attr("r", 5);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(30));

    simulation.nodes(nodes).on("tick", ticked);

//    simulation.stop();
    simulation.tick();
    simulation.tick(10);

    function ticked() {
        // console.log("Ticked");
        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_tick): *"This method does not dispatch events; events are only dispatched by the internal timer when the simulation is started automatically upon creation or by calling simulation.restart."* That means that your tick handler is not going to get called when manually ticking ahead. This will only do the math to ensure maximum performance; you are free to call the tick handler at your own discretion, though.

Comment: @altocumulus, indeed, I missed that. Is there a way to step through the simulation and see the effect of each step, starting with the initial position?

Comment: `while (simulation.alpha() > simulation.alphaMin()) { simulation.tick(); ticked(); }`

Comment: @altocumulus, very nice, please convert to an answer.

Comment: Not really in the mood right now. Please feel free to write a self-answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was provided by @altocumulus in the comments.

My code with `simulation.stop()` didn't work because `ticked()` was never called, so node position was not updated. As described in [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_tick) for `tick()`:

> This method does not dispatch events.

so `.on("tick", ticked)` didn't do anything. To address it, one may call `ticked()` after `tick()` manually:

```
while (simulation.alpha() > simulation.alphaMin()) { simulation.tick(); ticked(); }
```